# Rails adding custom action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, routes

This might be very amateur question but I apparently do not know how to this, My question is, I have to make remove action on Index page, similar to delete action, but when I click on this button or link of a particular row in the table of index page, it should remove the item just from page(I know how to remove that item just from the page but not database) so my real problem how do I add this link for the button to remove that item, so when I click on the button it gets routed to that action in controller since the page is going to be the same how do I give path to it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do something like this:

```
<%= link_to "Delete", object_path(your_object), method: :delete %></td>
```

As long as you specify method: :delete you should be good to go.
So for example, if you are working with a user model you would do:

```
    <%= link_to "Delete", users_path(user), method: :delete %></td>
```

You will also have to make sure your routes are set. For example:

```
resources :users
```

Comment: "method: :delete" is the method name in controller ? or method in general like get post delete ?

Comment: and dont we have to add anything in the routes.rb file ?

Comment: method: :delete will trigger post delete. And you're absolutely right about the routes file. I've edited my original answer. Also, this example assumes you have a destroy action in your controller. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: method :delete will trigger delete action, what if I want to trigger a user defined action like say post "remove", do I put method: "remove" ?

Comment: In that case you would do something like <%= link_to "Remove", controller: users, action: remove %> Hard to say much more without seeing your controller code.

Comment: you can also write like this
    <%= link_to "Remove", remove_users_path(@user), :method => :delete %>

resouces :users do
    member do 
       delete 'remove'
    end
end